# How to make a POST request that only updates the provided fields?

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, post

I'm trying to make a post request with json data that only updated the provided fields. Currently, when I don't provide a field in the request body, it is reset to the default value.

when I send this:

```
{
    "id": 59706975,
    "maxRiskDollars": 1000,
    "maxRiskCashPercent": 0.01
}
```

I get this response

```
{
    "id": 59706975,
    "maxRiskDollars": 1000,
    "maxRiskCashPercent": 0.01
}
```

Then I send this:

```
{
    "id": 59706975,
    "maxRiskCashPercent": 0.02
}
```

and get this:

```
{
    "id": 59706975,
    "maxRiskDollars": 50,
    "maxRiskCashPercent": 0.02
}
```

(50 is the default value for maxRiskDollars)

how to I make it so that maxRiskDollars stays at the previous value when the field is not provided in the JSON request?

EDIT: 
Providing backend code as requested - this is JAVA/SPRING/HIBERNATE

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/tradeManagers")
TradeManager newTradeManager(@RequestBody TradeManager newTradeManager) {
    return tradeManagerRepo.save(newTradeManager);
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TradeManagerRepo extends CrudRepository<TradeManager, Long>{

}
```

Comment: May we see your code?

Comment: the POST request isn't the problem. The site that you are making your ajax request to isn't handling your request the way you want it to

Comment: @Benjamin Urquhart  sure I just edited the question to include my controller and repository

Comment: Well that doesn't help much

Comment: sorry but that's all there is to it - it's the plain vanilla out of the box spring implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Update Data, As per REST standards, Ideally a  PATCH or PUT HTTP call is made. I assume since you only want to update the fields provided in the json, it is more Likely to be a PATCH.

At the REST Controller you can accept a `Map<String, Object>` which would consist of only the fields that are supposed to be updated. 
A PATCH or PUT URL should have id of the resource that needs to be updated. 
Fetch the original object from the repo using FindById()

Then You could Use Something like [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)  (or any similar library that Spring provides out of the box) to copy only the properties from your source, ie Map to the destination Object.

```java
@PatchMapping("/tradeManagers/{tradeManagerId}")
Map<String, Object> newTradeManager(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> tradeManagerMap, 
    @PathVariable(name = "tradeManagerId") String trademanagerId) {
    Trademanager  tradeManger = tradeManagerRepo.findById(tradeManagerId);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(trademanager, tradeManagerMap);
    return tradeManagerMap;
}
```